# Snowflake Dotnet JWT Connection Issue

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone help me with the below error. my code working good on my local system but when i deploy my dotnet core web app on Azure App Service then its causing some issue with my connection certs.p8 file.

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net?tab=readme-ov-file#other-authentication-methods

**My Cert file is contains**

-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

**CODE**

```
string SNOWFLAKE_P8_PASSPHRASE = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SNOWFLAKE_P8_PASSPHRASE").ToString();

//CERT FILE PATH HERE
string APPLICATION_WWWROOT = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPLICATION_WWWROOT").ToString();
SnowflakeDbConnection connection;
var snowflakeDbConnectionStringBuilder = new SnowflakeDbConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                { "ACCOUNT", *** },
                { "AUTHENTICATOR", ***},
                { "USER", **** },
                { "private_key_file",  APPLICATION_WWWROOT},
                { "private_key_pwd", SNOWFLAKE_P8_PASSPHRASE },
                { "DB", *** },
                { "HOST", *** },
                { "ROLE", ***},
                { "Warehouse",***},
                { "SCHEMA",  *** }
            };
connection = new SnowflakeDbConnection(snowflakeDbConnectionStringBuilder.ToString());
if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) connection.Open();

DATABASE_CONNECTION_IS_OPEN = connection.IsOpen();
```

**ERROR**

```
Message=Error: Could not read private key rsa_key.p8. \n Error : Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemException: problem creating ENCRYPTED private key: System.ArgumentException: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: corrupted stream detected
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Asn1Sequence.GetInstance(Object obj) in /_/crypto/src/asn1/Asn1Sequence.cs:line 41
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo.GetInstance(Object obj) in /_/crypto/src/asn1/pkcs/PrivateKeyInfo.cs:line 69
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(Char[] passPhrase, Boolean wrongPkcs12Zero, EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encInfo) in /_/crypto/src/pkcs/PrivateKeyInfoFactory.cs:line 270
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(Char[] passPhrase, EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encInfo) in /_/crypto/src/pkcs/PrivateKeyInfoFactory.cs:line 253
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Security.PrivateKeyFactory.DecryptKey(Char[] passPhrase, EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encInfo) in /_/crypto/src/security/PrivateKeyFactory.cs:line 296
   at Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader.ReadPrivateKey(PemObject pemObject) in /_/crypto/src/openssl/PEMReader.cs:line 345
   at Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader.ReadPrivateKey(PemObject pemObject) in /_/crypto/src/openssl/PEMReader.cs:line 367
   at Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader.ReadObject() in /_/crypto/src/openssl/PEMReader.cs:line 97
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.Authenticator.KeyPairAuthenticator.GenerateJwtToken() SqlState: , VendorCode: 270052, QueryId:  StackTrace=   at Snowflake.Data.Core.Authenticator.KeyPairAuthenticator.GenerateJwtToken()
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.Authenticator.KeyPairAuthenticator.Authenticate()
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.SFSession.Open()
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.Session.SessionPool.NewSession(String connectionString, SecureString password)
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.Session.SessionPool.GetSession(String connStr, SecureString password)
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.Session.ConnectionCacheManager.GetSession(String connectionString, SecureString password)
   at Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnectionPool.GetSession(String connectionString, SecureString password)
   at Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnection.Open()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /Users/atomar10/Downloads/temp_app/-MyNewApp/Program.cs:line 31  InnerException=Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemException: problem creating ENCRYPTED private key: System.ArgumentException: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: corrupted stream detected
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Asn1Sequence.GetInstance(Object obj) in /_/crypto/src/asn1/Asn1Sequence.cs:line 41
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo.GetInstance(Object obj) in /_/crypto/src/asn1/pkcs/PrivateKeyInfo.cs:line 69
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(Char[] passPhrase, Boolean wrongPkcs12Zero, EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encInfo) in /_/crypto/src/pkcs/PrivateKeyInfoFactory.cs:line 270
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(Char[] passPhrase, EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encInfo) in /_/crypto/src/pkcs/PrivateKeyInfoFactory.cs:line 253
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Security.PrivateKeyFactory.DecryptKey(Char[] passPhrase, EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encInfo) in /_/crypto/src/security/PrivateKeyFactory.cs:line 296
   at Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader.ReadPrivateKey(PemObject pemObject) in /_/crypto/src/openssl/PEMReader.cs:line 345
   at Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader.ReadPrivateKey(PemObject pemObject) in /_/crypto/src/openssl/PEMReader.cs:line 367
   at Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader.ReadObject() in /_/crypto/src/openssl/PEMReader.cs:line 97
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.Authenticator.KeyPairAuthenticator.GenerateJwtToken()
```